# laravel 5 multiple upload and store their name into database

Tags: php, laravel, file-upload, laravel-5

i am currently following this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31936336/laravel-5-1-how-to-upload-multiple-files-from-three-different-file-input-fields) and here is my code

```
public function add(Request $request) {
$files=[];
if($request->file('remind_letter')) $files[]=$request->file('file1');
if($request->file('answer_note')) $files[]=$request->file('file2');
if($request->file('negotiation')) $files[]=$request->file('file3');
foreach($files as $file){
if(!empty($file){
$filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();
$extension = $file->getClientOriginalExtension();
Storage::disk('local')->put($filename.'.'.$extension,
                                         File::get($filename));
$entry = new Docks();
$entry->div = $request->input('div');
$entry->year = $request->input('year');
$entry->activity = $request->input('activity');
$entry->corporate = $request->input('corporate');
--- need logic to save their path into databse ----
$entry->save
```

and i am still confuse how to save their path into database
it is should be like this ?

```
$entry->remind_letter = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension
$entry->answer_note= $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension
$entry->negotiation = $file->getFilename().'.'.$extension
```

Comment: Why don't you have `$` before `files`?

Comment: @OzanKurt, ups, that fatal mistake it should `$files = [];` thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can assign filename using only `$filename=$file->getClientOriginalName();`
This will give you full file name included original extension.

Let's assume you want to upload your files into the folder '/public/files/'.

I suggest you use this inside your foreach:

```
if( !empty($file) )
{
    $file->move(base_path() . '/public/files/', $file->getClientOriginalName());
}
```

then for store filepath inside database ( I'm using filepath property as example):

```
$entry->filepath = base_path() . '/public/files/' . $file->getClientOriginalName();
```

In this way you will save the file where you desire and then have a full path to your file stored inside database.

Comment: let me try, so if i using `$entry->filepath=base_path()`, it will return pathfile in db each column, like file remind_letter into column `remind_letter` ,  `answer_note` into column `answer_note`, and `negotiation` into column `negotiation` ?

Comment: `base_path()` will return only your application root path, not the file path.
For this reason you have to give full file path like in the example i wrote above