# laravel using switch cases to upload files

Tags: laravel, laravel-4, laravel-5, laravel-5.3

how can i upload inputs files in different folders i need to use switch cases to make every input file in different folder and did this code but when i execute it nothing happen i want know where problem

my view

```
{!! Form::file('file1', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::file('file2', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::file('file3', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
{!! Form::file('file4', null,['class'=>'form-control']) !!}
```

my controler

```
$model = new Files($request->all());
        switch ($model) {
            case "file1":
                if ($request->hasFile('file1')) {
                    $file = $request->file('file1');
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/file1';
                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                    $request['file1'] = $filename;
                    $model -> file1 = $filename;
                    $model->save();
                }
                break;
            case "file2":
                if ($request->hasFile('file2')) {
                    $file = $request->file('file2');
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/file2';
                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                    $request['file2'] = $filename;
                    $model->file2 = $filename;
                    $model->save();
                }
                break;
                case "file3":
                if ($request->hasFile('file3')) {
                    $file = $request->file('file3');
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/file3';
                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                    $request['file3'] = $filename;
                    $model->file3 = $filename;
                    $model->save();
                }
                    break;
            case "file4":
                if ($request->hasFile('file4')) {
                    $file = $request->file('file4');
                    $destinationPath = public_path() . '/file4';
                    $filename = $file->getClientOriginalName();
                    $file->move($destinationPath, $filename);
                    $request['file4'] = $filename;
                    $model->file4 = $filename;
                    $model->save();
                }
                break;
        }
```

Comment: if you dd($model) what does it return? also when you do a switch it will stop after the first one that matches the case, so if you are wanting to do multiple you will need to do a foreach in the inputs and run them through the switch

Comment: Can you show the code for the model?

Comment: This looks suspiciously like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45075572/laravel-upload-files-in-many-inputs/45075789#45075789

Comment: no its not like the link this files in folders

Comment: mu model code protected $table = 'Files'; protected $fillable =['file1','file2','file3','file4'];

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ummm yeah I had do something like that, but I do it use `foreach` loop and `if` after that.

And here's my sample code, I hope it can help :-D

```
$requests = $request->all();
$model =  new File;
foreach ($requests as $key => $val) {
   if ($key == 'file1' && !empty($val)) {

       $destinationPath = public_path() . '/file1';
       $filename = $val->getClientOriginalName();
       $val->move($destinationPath, $filename);
       $model -> file1 = $filename;
       $model->save();
   }
   if ($key == 'file2' && !empty($val)) {

       $destinationPath = public_path() . '/file2';
       $filename = $val->getClientOriginalName();
       $val->move($destinationPath, $filename);
       $model -> file1 = $filename;
       $model->save();
   }
   // And do it again as much as you need :D
}
```

Here you go, I hope it can help you pals :D

Comment: Aha Glad can help you :D